# MS-Access 2013 Connecting stored procedure result to combobox recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb

AS in topic, I need to connect stored procedure results as recordset. Using some examples I found I came up with:

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
cn = GetConnection()
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With cmd
 .ActiveConnection = GetConnection()
 .CommandText = "dbo.K_Kod_Agenta_P"
 .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

 .Parameters.Refresh
End With
With rs
.ActiveConnection = GetConnection()
.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
.CursorLocation = adUseServer

End With

Set rs = cmd.Execute


Set Me.kod_nadagenta.Recordset = rs

rs.Close
cn.Close
```

But when it hits

```
Set Me.kod_nadagenta.Recordset = rs
```

it throws

"Run-time error '7965': The object you entered is not a valid Recordset property."

Answer (score 1):

Just create a pass-through query with the following SQL:

```
dbo.K_Kod_Agenta_P
```

Now simply base the  combo box on that pass-through query. You don’t need all that code.